# "There was/were my brother and two sisters?

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, be, coordinating-conjunctions

"There was [or were?] my brother and two sisters, hugging and tears streaming."

I've come across a sentence while editing, and I don't know whether to use "was" or "were." The object of the "be"-verb is a compound joined by "and."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a rule for using verbs with the conjunction "and" and with the conjunction "or". Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: *My brother and two sisters* is a plural subject; it describes 3 people.

Comment: *My brother and two sisters* is not the object of the verb. For one thing, linking verbs don't have objects. For another, *my brother and two sisters* is the true subject of the verb. The *there* is a dummy subject. The verb agrees with the true subject. (*were*)

Comment: @TinfoilHat "dummy subject"? What's that? "There" is the complement.  It is an adverb.

Comment: @phoog: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects

Comment: @TinfoilHat but "there are" in this sentence does not have the same function as in the linked examples.

Comment: @phoog: Now that I reread the sentence . . . you are likely right. Though, depending on the context, a dummy *there* reading is still possible. Either way, the subject is at the end.